# PHP Slim how to check if a request is application/json

Tags: php, slim, content-type

I want to be sure that the Content Type header of a request is application/json, how can I do with Slim framework?

This is not valid:

```
$contentType = $app->request->getContentType();
if(strtolower($contentType)!="application/json")
            throw new AppException("Request must have application/json content type");
```

because content type can contain charset info and so on...

Comment: Why don't you just check the presence of `application/json` substring in that header?

Comment: I didn't know if this is enought

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can inspect the header instead of using the short-cut

```
$cType = $app->request->headers('Content-Type');
if (strpos('application/json', $cType) !== false) {
    //is json
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure you got the arguments in `strpos` switched around. You want to search `$cType` for `application/json`, not the other way around. Your method fails on `application/json;charset=UTF-8`. Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Answer (score 0):

For people who search for a solution which is working in every situations, Illya Moskvin was right, the arguments are switched in the geggleto answer.
Here is the code example :

```
$contentType = $request->getContentType();
if (strpos($contentType, 'application/json') !== false) {
  //is json
}
```

You can use `stripos` instead which's case-insensitive but less performant or apply `strtolower` to `$contentType`

Answer (score -1):

I am playing with a newer version of Slim 3 and get into the same problem.

Here is a solution which worked for me (from inside of the specific controller)

```
$request_type = $request->getHeader('CONTENT_TYPE');
    if($request_type[0] != 'application/json'){
        // throw error    
        return $response->withStatus(415)
            ->withHeader('Content-type', 'text/html')
            ->write('Only json content type accepted');
    }
```

Maybe this would help someone.

Comment: Expectations have no place in code. Header could for example be "application/json; charset=utf-8" and your code would fail.